# Prevent program termination while go blocks execute indefinitely?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, core.async

I've written a standalone uberjar with a main method that spins off two go blocks like so:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (let [c (chan)]
    (go (while true
           (>! c (rand))))
    (go (while true
           (<! c)))))
```

But when I execute the program it quickly terminates. Why? My intention is to have the go blocks execute indefinitely. I ended up sticking

```
 (<!! (chan))
```

at the end of the main function to prevent termination. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: So there is no way to cleanly exit your application?

Comment: I'm relying on Ctrl+C.

Comment: @AustinC: This is exactly your problem. When you are designing async dataflows with infinite dispatch loops, you need your own cancellation conditionals. In `core.async` cancellation is usually communicated from the producer to the consumer by invoking `close!` on the producer side and then dispatching `nil` on the consumer side. Here is some example code: https://www.refheap.com/21103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program terminates because, after those `go` blocks are created, the main function is finished. With nothing to do, it exits; that shouldn't be much of a surprise. Of course, we'd prefer the main application keep running while all of those `go` blocks are still alive.

Each of those `go` blocks produces a channel; you could wait until one of them returns something (though as it stands, they never will). Try blocking with [`alts!!`](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/alts!!) while they spin:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [c (chan)]
    (alts!!
      [(go (while true
             (>! c (rand))))
       (go (while true
             (<! c)))])))
```

So, your main thread will block until one of the channels in `alts!!` returns a value. Right now, it'll block forever, but this structure sets you up for more interesting things. For example, you could exit the application when the random value is above some threshold:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [c (chan)]
    (alts!!
      [(go (while true
             (>! c (rand))))
       (go-loop [value (<! c)]
                (if (> value 0.8)
                  value ; return value from the go block
                  (recur (<! c))))])))
```

Or, go wild, timeout after a second:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [c (chan)]
    (alts!!
      [(go (while true
             (>! c (rand))))
       (go (while true
             (<! c)))
       (timeout 1000)])))
```

The larger takeaway is that there's a good chance you're going to want to block your main thread to wait for those asynchronous `go` blocks to finish up their business.